# Hide skipped sections in responses

Tags: google-forms

So, I've got an example form here with some conditionals. The flow is intended that it skips ahead to a specific section depending on the initial response—the usual.

My issue, however, is when reviewing the individual responses to this form because ALL sections are displayed, including those that were skipped over and left unfilled. In a longer form, this can turn into a major waste of time having to scroll through all those blank sections when all I want is to extract the relevant data from the individual responses.

Here's an example to show my issue:

[image]

Depending on the option in the image above, it'll proceed to a specific section, ignoring the others.

That works just fine, BUT when I then proceed to review the responses it looks like this:

[image: Responses page]

It shows the pages that were skipped over (in this case "Shirt example" is visible despite being skipped/irrelevant to the response)! This is completely unnecessary and a waste of space because I have to scroll past it to get to the actual relevant data and I'd like to hide all blank/unfilled/skipped sections so that I can review the responses more efficiently with less unnecessary scrolling.

I know I could open it as a spreadsheet but this is not at all ideal, especially in forms with long text fields to be filled out.

## tl;dr:

How can I simply hide any skipped/blank sections when reviewing individual responses? Such as the "Shirt example" section in the 2nd image?

Comment: currently, there is no workaround for that